# how to jam first column using jquery

Tags: php

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "300px",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bPaginate": false
    } );

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( oTable );
} );
```

this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear but if you want to stop sorting on first column in datatables use `aoColumns` keyword.
something like this

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "aoColumns": [
  { "bSortable": false },
  null,
  null,
  null
  ]
} );
```